# MySQL Table Lock Issue

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I think this might be a deadlock issue, but I'm only reading table data. Or something really simple I can't see.

My `$msqli` obj is fine for db access

But I'm a bit stumped about this error.. 
I am being told that the `clients` table is not being locked with `LOCK TABLES`

Any suggestions are welcome.. Thanks
Here is my PHP code

```
$mysqli = $GLOBALS['mysqli'];
$mysqli->query("LOCK TABLES clients READ, invoices READ, estimates READ");

$mysqli->query("SET @inv='Invoice'");
$mysqli->query("SET @est='Estimate'");

$sql = " (SELECT @inv, name AS client, invoices.id, invoices.ref AS ref, invoices.addTs AS ts \n"
        . "FROM `clients` , `invoices` \n"
        . "WHERE invoices.user_id =  " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " \n"
        . "AND clients.id = invoices.client_id)\n"
        . "UNION ALL\n"
        . "(SELECT @est, name as client, estimates.id, estimates.ref AS ref, estimates.addTs AS ts \n"
        . "FROM `clients` ,`estimates` \n"
        . "WHERE estimates.user_id =  " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " \n"
        . "AND clients.id = estimates.client_id) \n"
        . "ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))) {
//Do stuff here
}
```

When I run this `$sql` query in PhpMyAdmin it is successful... 
Thanks for any help..

*********************************SOLVED (?)* ******************************

**Fixed** (Or seems to be):

Quote from http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6588

> "you cannot use a locked table multiple times in one query - use aliases for that."

So the query is updated as

```
    $mysqli->query("LOCK TABLES clients_t READ,clients READ ,
                                invoices READ, estimates READ");
$mysqli->query("SET @inv='Invoice'");
$mysqli->query("SET @est='Estimate'");

$sql = " " .
        "(SELECT @inv, name AS client, invoices.id, 
                  invoices.ref AS ref, invoices.addTs AS ts "

        . "FROM `clients` AS clients_t , `invoices`\n"
        . "WHERE invoices.user_id =  " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . " \n"
        . "AND clients_t.id = invoices.client_id)\n"
        . "UNION ALL \n"
        . "(SELECT @est , name AS client, estimates.id, 
                   estimates.ref AS ref, estimates.addTs AS ts\n"
        . "FROM `clients` ,`estimates` \n"
        . "WHERE estimates.user_id =  " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "  \n"
        . "AND clients.id = estimates.client_id)\n"
        . "ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 5";
```

I also needed to lock the alias table `clients_t`.
Anyway for future users I hope this helps.

Comment: Please, provide exact error message

Comment: Error message is `Table 'clients' was not locked with LOCK TABLES` . I probably should have mentioned that this query was working before, but I was working on stuff for a few hours last night that I can't see should affect the query. Also if I change the `$sql` to "SELECT * FROM clients` it will work... So I suspect the `$sql` is the issue

Answer (score 0):

A little nit picky but it would be wise to do something such as addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string to the $_SESSION['user_id'] input to avoid injection issues.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew McGrath. I think that would be correct. Thanks for the advice. I have called functions on the GET, POST, REQUEST vars at the start of each page to clean them.